# Routage in Net 6, how to allow url {controller}/{action}/{id}/{string}

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

in the program.cs i found this line of code :

```
app.MapControllerRoute(
name: "default",
pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
```

but i am not sure how to do in order to allow my website to have such a URL :
[www.domain.com/mycontroller/id/title](http://www.domain.com/mycontroller/id/title)

Could you help me to make this happen?
what do i need to change?
and in the controller i need to add something?
and the link asp-action how should be?
Thanks

Comment: **1.** Mark your question with `asp.net-core-mvc` tag. **2.** The title contains `action` segment. Therefore make it consistent and correct URL inside the question description (or in the title). **3.** Show your code related to the `link asp-action`.

Comment: hi, i still have any code.. i actually ask how to do because i am lost withg NET 6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to  allow url `{controller}/{action}/{id}/{string}` in the controller,you can use like this:

```
[Route("[controller]/[action]")]
public class TestController : Controller
{
   [Route("{id}/{s}")]
   public IActionResut Test(string id,string s)
   {
       return View();
   }

}
```

If you want to use `<a>` tag:

```
<a asp-action="AddStudy" asp-route-id="xxx" asp-route-s="xxx">a</a>
```

Comment: Thanks frot he answer Yiyi, And in the in the program.cs i need to modify something?

Comment: No,I didn't change it.